# Url RewriteRule conditionals

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I am working on some SEO for my site, and using urls like `category/this-cat.html` and `category/this-cat-p2.html` to redirect to `index.php?mode=viewCat&id=this-cat` and `index.php?mode=viewCat&id=this-cat&start=10` respectively.
The problem is that my RewriteRule needs a conditional to check if the `-p2` part is present in the URL, and then return either 0 or the digit after `p`.

Current rule:

`RewriteRule ^category/(.*?)\.html$ index.php?mode=viewCat&title=$1`

I would have thought that the correct syntax for this would have been:

`RewriteRule ^category/(.*?)(?(-p)(.*?)|0)\.html$ index.php?mode=viewCat&title=$1&start=$2`

however, this causes the server to return a 500 error.
Even after having read tutorials and worked with them for the past week, I still have little grasp on them. Can anyone explain how to make a conditional like this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. I believe what you are trying to do is not capture the optional `-p#` grouping, but want the digit if it exists. The non-capture flag for a group is a `?:` prefix.

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*?)(?:-p(\d+))?\.html$ index.php?mode=viewCat&title=$1&start=$2
```

**Note:** I used `\d` (digit) as it's better to be specific about what you are matching. Also `start` will have a digit or nothing. Your server-side code is better suited to handle the rest of the logic you described.